# How to swap each case of a character in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to Write a JavaScript program which accept a string as input and swap the case of each character. For example if you input 'The Quick Brown Fox' the output should be 'tHE qUICK bROWN fOX'

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this by using one of the approach:

```
const str = "The Quick Brown Fox";

const result = str
  .split("")
  .map(item => (item === item.toUpperCase() ? item.toLowerCase() : item.toUpperCase()))
  .join("");

console.log(result);
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much @Shivanshu Gupta for answering my question